# Lebesgue measure of subset of $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $E$ be the subset of $\mathbb R$ and Lebesgue measure $\lambda(E)$ is positive. Is it true that $\lambda(E)= \lambda(-E)$? I tried it for interval and found true. I tried with infimum definition of measure of set. I think it is true but I am not sure. Please tell me complete proof if it is true or counter example otherwise.

Comment: see property 16 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure#Properties

Comment: Since measure $\mu(A)=\lambda(-A)$ coincide with $\lambda$ on algebra of intervals, they are also the same on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the algebra of intervals by Charatheodory extension theorem (and Legesgue measure is just completion of Borel measure).

Comment: Of course, intervals forms half-algebra, not algebra, so substitute algebra with half-algebra in the comment above

Comment: @ZoranLoncarevic what about $\lambda(E) = \lambda (E^{0})$ ? Is it true? where $E^{0}$ is interior of $E$

Comment: @ArunSharma No, it is not true. For example,if $E=\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$, then $\lambda(E)=\infty$ and $\lambda(E^0)=0$.

Comment: @Zoran Loncarevic how $\lambda (E^{0}) =0$? in this case. Can u plz explain?

Comment: Well, interior of $E$ is empty set.

Comment: @ZoranLoncarevic : how do you define the interior of a set $E$...

Comment: Oh yes, Thank You so much.

Comment: so in the context of Lebesgue measure, I don't see why you wouldn't say that the interior is the set of non isolated points, and in that case $E^0 = E$

Comment: @ZoranLoncarevic : so I meant isolated = not the limit of a sequence of points of the set. what I mean is that instead of saying "this is not true" you had to say "you have to be careful with the definition of $E^0$ for it to be true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that $s\in[0,\infty)$ is element of $S_E$ if there are open intervals $(a_i,b_i)$ with $s=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}b_i-a_i$ and $E\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}(a_i,b_i)$

Then by definition $\lambda(E):=\inf(S_E)$.

On base of $$E\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}(a_i,b_i)\iff-E\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}(-b_i,-a_i)$$

we find that $S_E=S_{-E}$ and consequently $\lambda E=\lambda (-E)$.

Comment: What about $\lambda(E) = \lambda(E^{0})$ ? Where $E^{0}$  is interior of $E$.

Comment: I see no relation with your original question. Is there any? If not then you could pose another question.

Comment: Under the same hypothesis, I am looking these equalities. I have done for measure closure of $E$ is not same as measure of $E$ and many others with conter examples.

Comment: Well, have a look at $E=\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$. We have $E^{\circ}=\varnothing$ so $\lambda(E^{\circ})=0$ but $\lambda(E)=\infty$.